# SSL Error when attempting to load LM1B dataset

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch

I am attempting to train and sample the Diffusion-BERT model from [here](https://github.com/Hzfinfdu/Diffusion-BERT/tree/main).

When a try to run the word_freq.py file, which looks like this:

```py
import os

from transformers import BertTokenizer, RobertaTokenizer
import torch
from dataloader import DiffusionLoader
import numpy as np
import diffusion_word_freq
import math
from tqdm import tqdm

# tokenizer = RobertaTokenizer.from_pretrained('roberta-base')
tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
train_data = DiffusionLoader(tokenizer=tokenizer).my_load(task_name='lm1b', splits=['train'])[0]
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
Downloading and preparing dataset lm1b/plain_text to /root/.cache/huggingface/datasets/lm1b/plain_text/1.0.0/694f4d1f8a28b4eefe3151693c199fd216ab51c4f947fd5b007abe4d774b79e0...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/content/Diffusion-BERT/word_freq.py", line 13, in <module>
    train_data = DiffusionLoader(tokenizer=tokenizer).my_load(task_name='lm1b', splits=['train'])[0]
  File "/content/Diffusion-BERT/dataloader.py", line 20, in my_load
    return [self._load(task_name, name) for name in splits]
  File "/content/Diffusion-BERT/dataloader.py", line 20, in <listcomp>
    return [self._load(task_name, name) for name in splits]
  File "/content/Diffusion-BERT/dataloader.py", line 13, in _load
    dataset = datasets.load_dataset('lm1b', split=split)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/datasets/load.py", line 1757, in load_dataset
    builder_instance.download_and_prepare(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/datasets/builder.py", line 860, in download_and_prepare
    self._download_and_prepare(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/datasets/builder.py", line 1611, in _download_and_prepare
    super()._download_and_prepare(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/datasets/builder.py", line 931, in _download_and_prepare
    split_generators = self._split_generators(dl_manager, **split_generators_kwargs)
  File "/root/.cache/huggingface/modules/datasets_modules/datasets/lm1b/694f4d1f8a28b4eefe3151693c199fd216ab51c4f947fd5b007abe4d774b79e0/lm1b.py", line 94, in _split_generators
    archive = dl_manager.download(_DOWNLOAD_URL)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/datasets/download/download_manager.py", line 331, in download
    downloaded_path_or_paths = map_nested(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/datasets/utils/py_utils.py", line 436, in map_nested
    return function(data_struct)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/datasets/download/download_manager.py", line 357, in _download
    return cached_path(url_or_filename, download_config=download_config)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/datasets/utils/file_utils.py", line 183, in cached_path
    output_path = get_from_cache(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/datasets/utils/file_utils.py", line 533, in get_from_cache
    raise ConnectionError(f"Couldn't reach {url} ({repr(head_error)})")
ConnectionError: Couldn't reach http://www.statmt.org/lm-benchmark/1-billion-word-language-modeling-benchmark-r13output.tar.gz (SSLError(MaxRetryError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.statmt.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /lm-benchmark/1-billion-word-language-modeling-benchmark-r13output.tar.gz (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: certificate has expired (_ssl.c:1007)')))")))
```

Is it just because the site isn't secure? Is there anything I can do to solve this error?

I'm running this in Google Colab.